# How to connect Node.js API to Oracle DB

Tags: mysql, oracle, api, connection

I have my backend with this connection pool in mysql, now I try to migrate to dabase oracle can someone help me with configuration (to connect my api to oracle DB) thank you very much.

**.env**

```
APP_PORT=3000
DB_PORT=8889
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=root
MYSQL_DB=test  


**dabatase.js**

const { createPool } = require('mysql');

const pool = createPool({
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
    connectionLimit: 10
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Comment: what exactly is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: This configuration works fine for database MySQL, but I need to reconfigure it for database oracle. ( I want to migrate to DB Oracle )

Comment: Here's the node-oracledb documentation: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html Here's the installation manual: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html

Comment: Thank you veru much, I will follow the instructions !